# Apple maps find nearest location on the road or in the park

Tags: ios, google-maps, geocoding, apple-maps

My iOS application use Apple Maps and need to find the nearest coordinates on the road or in the park. I cant find in API methods for that. Perhaps for this purpose is better to use Google Maps. How can i do it?
I find some similar, but there is no straight answer.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19815248/558933

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenStreetMap query:

```
<query type="way">
  <around {{center}} radius="100.0"/>
  <has-kv k="highway"  />
</query>
<print />
```

example (see the data): http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/3iK